# Generic Question Sheet

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a generic document with questions. Something that might encompass a survey and a quiz simultaneously. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possibly questionaire?

Answer (score 1):

***[questionnaire](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/questionnaire)***

> A set of printed or written questions with a choice of answers,
>   devised for the purposes of a survey or statistical study.